# Up Voting/Down Voting should be listed in activity

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes, list, activity

I think it would be convenient if the activity page also lists the moments whenever I Up Vote or Down Vote a post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is listed in the activity page then **it wont be anonymous anymore**.

Also why do you want to know about which question/answers you have up/down voted. In worst case, you will anyway know when you see the highlighted up/down arrow on the post which you have up/down voted anyway.

Comment: what is the question of anonymity here?

Comment: @Gunner - Other users can see your activity too. ;)